# Jira Smart Commits Not Running Commands

Tags: git, github, jira, smart-commits

My Jira Smart Commits are correctly being tracked by a Jira Ticket

[image: Proving the linkage of my commits to my Jira Ticket]

but my commands are not being executed. Example commit I'm attempting to get executed by Jira Smart Commits:

`$ git commit -m "Foo-2 Fake commit where I moved a task from Backlog to In Progress #time 1h $in-progress"`

I've read through all the documentation listed here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-smart-commits-298979931.html

*Note, the link above may require an atlassian login. Since I'm answering my own question immediately, I'm providing the link above for completion sake.*

Answer (score 10):

This took longer than I'd care to admit. This link here:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Core-questions/Smart-commit-not-working/qaq-p/387358

Has described exactly the problem I was running into. Quoting the important text for completeness:

> ...if there is no email in the commit matching any jira user it won't work (gets rejected).

I was getting a silent rejection from Jira, because the email on my Github account, seen by running `$ git config --global user.email`, did **not** match the email address on my Jira account.

The silentness of this issue was what got me, as you can see above, I was able to attribute commits to specific Jira tasks **without** having a matching email address.

I hope this saves at least one person a massive headache and confusion.

Comment: You seem smarter than your commits ;-) thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @RomainValeri I assure you its just an optical illusion!

Comment: Omg it's 2022 and this solution is life saver :)
1:00 AM - Issue Solved, big :beer: for you @GregHilston

Comment: @MarcinWaśniowski it brings me so much joy to know that I've helped someone ha :) cheers and Ty for the beer